# How can I have the spinner load only before the data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to have my `Spinner` component show only before the API data is loaded, otherwise, it should be hidden. I created a variable called `value` and set it to `true` whenever the API info is fetched but I seem to be getting it wrong when using the `v-if` and `v-else` directives. At the moment only one component is loaded when using the `v-if`.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm new to Vue.js and I've seen the directive called `v-cloak` but I'm not particularly sure how to use it.

```
<template lang="">
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Spinner v-if="!value" />
        <CryptoList v-else v-bind:crypts="cryptoData" />
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import Header from "./components/Header";
    import CryptoList from "./components/CryptoList";
    import Spinner from "./components/Spinner";
    import axios from "axios";
    const API_KEY = "ed599676c60cb5b0b369519d8cadaa8a";

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                cryptoData: [],
                value: null
            };
        },
        name: "App",
        components: {
            Header,
            CryptoList,
            Spinner
        },
        methods: {
            isMounted() {
                return (this.value = false);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios
                .get(`https://api.nomics.com/v1/currencies/ticker?key=${API_KEY}`, {
                    params: {
                        "per-page": "100",
                        "page": 1,
                        "rank": 1
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.cryptoData = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

            this.value = true;
            console.log(this.value);
        }
    };
</script>
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        font-family: "Baloo 2";
        font-weight: lighter;
        color: #e7e7de;
        background-image: url("./img/background.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `this.value = true` before your Axios request?

Comment: I would wrap your ajax call in a method/function, something like `getPage()`. In this method you would set `value` to true and in the `finally()` part of the ajax/promise set `value` to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `this.value = true` ***before*** the API call returns. You have to do it after:

```
mounted() {
  axios
   .get(...)
     .then((response) => {
        this.cryptoData = response.data;
        // <= here the API call returned (you're inside the promise)
        this.value = true;
     });
  // <= here API call has not returned yet. (you're outside the promise)
  //    you're in mounted, right after the API call was made
}
```

---

An alternative approach is to turn `value` into a `computed` returning `true/false` based on current value of `cryptoData`'s length:

```
data: () => ({
   cryptoData: []
}),
computed: {
  value() {
    return !!this.cryptoData.length;
  }
},
mounted() {
  axios
    .get(...)
       .then((response) => {
         this.cryptoData = response.data;
       });
}
```

Whenever you want to show the spinner again, all you have to do is empty `cryptoData`:

```
this.cryptoData = [];
```

I would also advise you to work on your naming practices (as a general rule, naming variables or properties `value`, `what`, `when`, `who`, `some`, `few`, is considered bad practice). Good practice is using descriptive names, announcing the role or the function performed. In this case, I'd rename `value` to `hasData` or maybe `isLoadingData`. Good coding and naming practices will save you time, money, hair, even jobs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice and I'll try out your solution

Comment: @TajC, welcome. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: I tried you're second solution and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help and advice